# How to save build warnings produced in CLion

Tags: logging, cmake, clion

Whenever I build in CLion, the message box pops up and prints out warnings. If I get too much of them though, the box cuts off and I can't scroll up to see the previous ones. Does CLion output these build messages into a log somewhere? And if not, how can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Terminal -> Terminal scrollback buffer size

[image]